iPad - List View - background to foreground - moves up
Happens only in iPad device.
Run the app, looks fine. Press home button, select app, below mentioned bugs happen (sometimes first time, sometimes 2nd, 3rd, 4th time)

The list in the sidebar moves up (space between top nav bar and list is lost)
The detail view's toolbar's items vanish (principal, leading, trailing vanish, bottom stays)

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            // Leading side (typically a list or navigation links)
            List {
                NavigationLink("Item 1", destination: detailView(text: "Detail View for Item 1"))
                NavigationLink("Item 2", destination: detailView(text: "Detail View for Item 2"))
                NavigationLink("Item 3", destination: detailView(text: "Detail View for Item 3"))
                NavigationLink("Item 4", destination: detailView(text: "Detail View for Item 4"))
                NavigationLink("Item 5", destination: detailView(text: "Detail View for Item 5"))
                NavigationLink("Item 6", destination: detailView(text: "Detail View for Item 6"))
                NavigationLink("Item 7", destination: detailView(text: "Detail View for Item 7"))
                NavigationLink("Item 8", destination: detailView(text: "Detail View for Item 8"))
                NavigationLink("Item 9", destination: detailView(text: "Detail View for Item 9"))
                NavigationLink("Item 10", destination: detailView(text: "Detail View for Item 10"))
                NavigationLink("Item 11", destination: detailView(text: "Detail View for Item 11"))
                NavigationLink("Item 12", destination: detailView(text: "Detail View for Item 12"))
                NavigationLink("Item 13", destination: detailView(text: "Detail View for Item 13"))
                NavigationLink("Item 14", destination: detailView(text: "Detail View for Item 14"))
                NavigationLink("Item 15", destination: detailView(text: "Detail View for Item 15"))
                NavigationLink("Item 16", destination: detailView(text: "Detail View for Item 16"))
                NavigationLink("Item 17", destination: detailView(text: "Detail View for Item 17"))
                NavigationLink("Item 18", destination: detailView(text: "Detail View for Item 18"))
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                    Text("Items")
                }
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                         Button(action: {
                            let _ = print("going back to main screen")
                        })
                        {
                            Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
                        }
                    }
                }
        } detail: {
            // Default detail view when nothing is selected
            Text("Select an Item")
        }
    }
    
    // Function to generate a detail view with a principal toolbar item
    @ViewBuilder
    func detailView(text: String) -> some View {
        Text(text)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                    Text(text)
                }
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    Text("Trailing")
                }
                ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) {
                    Text("Bottom")
                }
            }
    }
}

// Preview
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}


The title in the sidebar has only been scrolled up, it can be scrolled down again. But the disappearance of the top toolbar in the detail view seems like a bug to me.

A workaround for the scrolled title is to use a section title for the List, instead of using a navigation title:

List {
    Section {
        // list items
    } header: {
        Text("Title") // or "" to show just a gap
            .font(.largeTitle)
            .fontWeight(.bold)
    }
}
.navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
.navigationTitle("")



A workaround for the disappearing top toolbar is to make the toolbar dependent on the scenePhase:

@Environment (\.scenePhase) private var scenePhase

Text(text)
    .toolbar {
        if scenePhase == .active {
            // toolbar items as before
        }
    }

Putting it all together (and using a ForEach for the list items):
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment (\.scenePhase) private var scenePhase
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {

            // Leading side (typically a list or navigation links)
            List {
                Section {
                    ForEach(1...18, id: \.self) { n in
                        NavigationLink("Item \(n)", destination: detailView(text: "Detail View for Item \(n)"))
                    }
                } header: {
                    Text("Title") // or "" to show just a gap
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .navigationTitle("")
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                    Text("Items")
                }
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                    Button {
                        let _ = print("going back to main screen")
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
                    }
                }
            }
        } detail: {

            // Default detail view when nothing is selected
            Text("Select an Item")
        }
    }
    
    // Function to generate a detail view with a principal toolbar item
    @ViewBuilder
    func detailView(text: String) -> some View {
        Text(text)
            .toolbar {
                if scenePhase == .active {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                        Text(text)
                    }
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                        Text("Trailing")
                    }
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) {
                        Text("Bottom")
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}



Thank you for posting an answer. But I need to support iOS 15.0 onwards. And buildIf is available only 16.0 and up. Also for simplicity I showed an "Items" toolbar on sidebar, but in my app there is a multi option tool bar on top. So List Section header will also not work.

@niravdinmali The example in your question shows a NavigationSplitView, this is only available in iOS 16.

yes but for iOS 15.0 I use stack view. To simplify showing code I created a small app to put the code here and concentrating only on iOS 16 for here.
